# for-loop in for-loop doesn't execute in order with async/await function

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have a loop (with index j) in a loop (with index i) with an await function in it, after debug, I found sometimes some pair of (i,j) execute more than one time. I am totally confused -_-

Could someone explain it? Thanks so much!

Here is the code:

I add searchFunc to an input element.

```js
async function searchFunc() {
  let results = [];
  let notebooksP = await queryData(url1);
  notebooks = notebooksP.value;
  // debugger;
  for (let i = 0; i < notebooks.length; i++) {
    let noteIds;
    let noteIdsP = await queryData(urlBase + notebooks[i].id);
    noteIds = noteIdsP.value;
    debugger;
    for (let j = 0; j < noteIds.length; j++) {
      console.log("runing at i=", i, ", j=", j, );
      let noteContentsP = await queryData(urlBase + noteIds[j].id);
      let data = noteContentsP.value;
      // debugger;
      let content = data.content;
      let idx = content.search(key);
      if (idx != -1) {
        let res = {};
        res.notebookId = notebooks[i].id;
        res.noteId = noteIds[j].id;
        results.push(res);
        console.log("found at i=", i, " j=", j);
      }
    }
  }
```

```js
function queryData(path) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', path);
        xhr.send(null);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                var ret = xhr.responseText;
                resolve({value: JSON.parse(ret)});
            } else {
                reject('error');
            }
        }
    })
}
```

```js
const searchContent = debounce(searchFunc, 500);
searchBox.addEventListener('input', searchContent);

function debounce(fn, wait) {
    let timeout = null;
    return function () {
        if (timeout !== null) clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(fn, wait);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where are you running your searchFunc from?

Comment: Add `console.trace('searchFunc was called')` at the start of the `searchFunc` function. I think you'll find you have multiple calls in flight at the same time.  `console.trace` will dump a call stack to the console.  Look at that call stack to see who called `searchFunc` to account for both calls.  (I see two in your transcript)

Comment: Yes, it  called twice by setTImeout function in listener(I have add some code in the question to make it clear), could you please tell me how can I correct it?thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a design flaw here if you are triggering a search on every keypress. This can lead to problems with ordering of responses among other things. However, ignoring this issue, one simple way around the problem you are experiencing is simply to block the function from being called twice at the same time using a variable to track when it is running:

```
let searching = false;
async function searchFunc() {
  if (searching) {
    return;
  }
  searching = true;
  let results = [];
  let notebooksP = await queryData(url1);
  notebooks = notebooksP.value;
  // debugger;
  for (let i = 0; i < notebooks.length; i++) {
    let noteIds;
    let noteIdsP = await queryData(urlBase + notebooks[i].id);
    noteIds = noteIdsP.value;
    for (let j = 0; j < noteIds.length; j++) {
      console.log("runing at i=", i, ", j=", j, );
      let noteContentsP = await queryData(urlBase + noteIds[j].id);
      let data = noteContentsP.value;
      // debugger;
      let content = data.content;
      let idx = content.search(key);
      if (idx != -1) {
        let res = {};
        res.notebookId = notebooks[i].id;
        res.noteId = noteIds[j].id;
        results.push(res);
        console.log("found at i=", i, " j=", j);
      }
    }
  }
  searching = false;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please upvote/mark as answer if an answer helps you.